# Cannot step into Qt source

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

I create a Qt project, build the project with "msvc2017-32bit" kit, and debug the project in Qt Creator.

The problem is I can not step into the Qt functions. I can stop at break-points in my own source code, but cannot stop at break-points in files in Qt src directory. When I step into a Qt function, the message "*Stopped: "end-stepping-range"*" appears by the debugging buttons. Why could this happen?

I installed the debugger tools for Windows in Windows 10 SDK, but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you actually install the debug information/ is the qt dll build with debug information?

Comment: Yes, I use the official qt pre-build, which has the debug version of dlls such as Qt5Cored.dll. I saw this in debugger log: fullname="C:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/mingw482_32\\qtbase\\src\\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp", which is apparently not correct. Do not know how this fullname is formed.

Comment: Do you also link against those libs?

Comment: Yes, I link against those libs. I just create a simple qt widget project using the wizard. It can be built and run without problem. Just cannot debug it.

Comment: did you add the path of an installed compiler to the system path?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R
 I do not find the Visual Studio path and Windows SDK path(except E:\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\) in system path. But since I can build the project successfully, Qt Creator must have prepared the paths for the project.

Comment: did you have this problem with other compilers like Mingw or msvc2019?

Comment: I have some problem with adding MSYS2 compiler [this was my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732453/9484913) there I understand that should add `Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin` to the system path in upper priority. maybe you should do this .and I always use GDB as system debuger

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions from Qt [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html#debugging-tools-for-macos).

For Mac, the instructions are:

- In Projects->Build&Run->Run->Run Settings->Run, select "Use debug version of frameworks".

There are different instructions for Windows, but I have not tried it yet.

You probably also need to have QT sources installed.

Comment: I am on Windows, not MacOS. There is no "Use debug version of frameworks".

Comment: @William It is true, but there is a separate section in the same page with instructions for Windows. I have not tried it yet, though. Regardless, I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the MaintenanceTool and check if `Qt Creator 4.15.2 CDB Debugger Support` and `Debugging Tools for Windows` has been selected.

Comment: I only see Qt Creator CDB Debugger Support(selected and installed) under "Component Name/Developer and Designer Tools", when selecting "Add or remove components" option in MaintenanceTool. Can I download the "Debugging Tools for Windows" somewhere on download.qt.io?

Answer (score 1):

I run Qt on Windows, although a different compiler than you, and you can set the debug target paths by going to `Tools->Options->Debugger`. From here you can click a button `Add Qt sources...`. Below is an image of my setup and this works for me.

[image]

Comment: still not work. Qt creator seems to find the source C:\Qt\Qt5.12.6\5.12.6\Src\qtbase\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp as I can see in the stack view, but it cannot step into source of Qt classes like QWidget. In the debugger log window, I can see " Step into: Hit frame with no source, step out..."