# how add new MinGW compiler as kit in QT and windows 10

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to add one **kit to Qt**:

I download and install **MinGW** from  [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) because it has some more options than Qt  **default MinGW**, I want to build my app with this and use `CMake`.

I don't know how should do this, I see QT documentation and I do this  :

1.In `tools/options` I add a new manual kit

[image]

2.In compiler it autodetects but didn't recognize it and **I think this is a problem** but **I don't know how to fix it**

[image]

*here are the path and folders of **MinGW** that I installed.*

[image]

**If I want to add compiler manually which of these should I add in the c++ and c sections?**

I use **windows 10** and **Qt 5.15.2.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by doing the following things :

1. put [msys2](https://www.msys2.org) MinGW compiler **path in my system path** like this :

[image]

2. By doing this, QT Creator **autodetects** Compiler.

[image]

3. Add kit and set its name and compiler like [QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html)

[image]