# Cannot find feature windows_vulkan_sdk in qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have newly installed Qt and when I tried to open my projects and have not even tried to compile, I got this mysterious cannot find feature windows_vulkan.

My QT has been working earlier but I had to reinstall it because it complained I had missing libicuun65.dll and libicuuc65.dll and recommended reinstallation. I have removed everything and installed qt from scratch.

Below is my error

[image]

I went into the directory it specified and clearly see the file. I am just not sure the content of the file is complete as it only contains 2 lines below:

```
load(windows_vulkan_sdk)
QMAKE_LIBS_VULKAN       =
```

Maybe there are lib that are missing like libicuun65.dll and libicuuc65.dll and/or others?

Also, please note the uncompleted "Prepare C++ code Model" status bar. It has never completed as I saw it there for hours...it should not take that long.

What should I do to rectify this issue? Please help.

Update: My paths are set up too...

[image]

[image]

Comment: In windows, I think you should add the Vulkan path `into your system path`, did you do that? for example, I have an issue with `msys2` and I solve it by [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732453/9484913)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R- Thanks Parisa, I do have the environment path set correctly include the vulkan sdk

Comment: I think your problem is like this:https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76660

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why this happens for you, you install your Qt in `Drive D` but install Vulkan SDK in `Drive C`.

These should be **on the same Drive.**

Maybe Qt can't find your Vulkan SDK because of that please reinstall Vulkan SDK in `Drive D`.

another thing is [this link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76660) in `bugreports.qt.io`

and also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1681).

They have problems like you and their compiler was `MSYS2`.

> In
> \msys64\mingw32\qt5-static\share\qt5\mkspecs\common\windows-vulkan.conf
> changed:
>
> From: load(windows_vulkan_sdk)
>
> To: load(win32/windows_vulkan_sdk)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to uninstall Vulkan and reinstall Vulkan in drive D and see how it goes

Comment: I have now installed both Qt and Vulcan on C but the issue is still not solved.. it seems that it is still reading vulkan config from d:\...\windows_vulkan.cf while everything now is in C.. something is still not right.. just can not wrap my head around it..

Comment: @user1205746 Did you charged file`\msys64\mingw32\qt5-static\share\qt5\mkspecs\common\windows-vulkan.conf`
**load(windows_vulkan_sdk)** to load(win32/windows_vulkan_sdk) , it seems this is a bug related to compiling with msys2

Comment: In this link https://forum.qt.io/topic/107833/cannot-find-feature-windows_vulkan_sdk/8   ,he said that it will solve

Comment: No, I did not change the file. It was probably the remnant of the previous version. I originally installed qt 5 on D got the dlls issues and then reinstall qt 6 on C after uninstalled qt5. With qt 6, it is supposed to use a different path in C and not D. Plus my machine is 64bit, not sure why it is still accessing mingw32.. I am trying to figure out how to correct the pointer to 64 bit.. the link you provided helped and showed me the potential cause. I will need to figure how to fix it.

Comment: @user1205746 I hope you can do it please tell me too if you find it.

Comment: Well, the plot thickens.. turns out I do not have VulkanRT-installer. Got one and installed from the website.. try to run Vulkan cube and it failed because it could not find a compatible Vulkan installable client driver (ICD).. I do not have NVIDIA just the normal Intel Graphic... so I am not sure how to proceed.. it was not like that in the previous QT version... I am lost

Comment: It seems This is a BUG, and sterange

Comment: @user1205746, well, I have a suggestion, In such a case, I didn't use windows. I have one ubuntu near my windows that I install dual boot, you can use VMWare too. This problem seems that is one BUG and It takes time, maybe in the Future they Fix this issue. But for now, I test the `hellovulkancubes` Example in Ubuntu 20.04 and Qt 6.2.3 and it runs successfully. although I have NVIDIA too

Comment: @user1205746 Another thing that comes to my mind is your `compiler.` Can you change it to something that is not Mingw? Like `MSVC 2019 or 2015`??

Comment: I changed it to MSVC 2019.. no luck.. it is very weird

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling qt again, now I get this error when I open my project:: D:\MSys2\mingw64\share\qt5\mkspecs\features\win32\windows_vulkan_sdk.prf:8: error: contains(): Encountered invalid regular expression 'C:\VulkanSDK\1.3.211.0/include'. This qt is driving me crazy

Comment: The content of windows_vulkan_sdk.prf is: isEmpty(QMAKE_INCDIR_VULKAN) {

    QMAKE_INCDIR_VULKAN = $$(VULKAN_SDK)/include

    # Do not add default include paths as that can knock std headers
    # out of their stride due to their usage of #include_next.
    contains(QMAKE_DEFAULT_INCDIRS, $$QMAKE_INCDIR_VULKAN): \
        QMAKE_INCDIR_VULKAN =

    QMAKE_EXPORT_INCDIR_VULKAN = -
}